# Custom message when JUnit assert fails

Tags: java, testing, junit, assert

I want to include a line separator (horizontal line of hyphens) before and after the assert failure message so that they are more visible and can be easily found in log.

Is there I can do this in a way that it shows up for when any assert fails? Naive way of doing this of course is to add the line separator strings to each assertEquals method.

Comment: Which build tool are you using?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with test listener. Create test listener extention from RunListener  [RunListener](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html) overide method

```
public void testFailure(Failure failure) throws Exception
```

> Called when an atomic test fails, or when a listener throws an
>   exception.